# Is there a function to create livewire component with js?

Tags: javascript, laravel-livewire

Please can I create a livewire component with javascript and mount it on the dom when user perfoms an action?

I don't know how I can do it. The principal problem is if I refresh a parent component(the container) I'll do many database request on a action.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.